# Check if a package will build

Tags: go, build

How can I determine if a package will build, without installing it, running its tests, or generating a binary?

There's a mention that using `go build` with more than one package just tests if they build. How can I do that for a single package?

Comment: That's what `go build` does, except for `main` packages. Maybe just remove the binary afterwards if it's a `package main`?

Comment: `go build bla && go clean bla`, maybe?

Comment: Just plain `go build`. Without any arguments it builds the package in the current directory (or gives an error if it can't). For a named package `go build import_path` works. Other than the temporary build dir which is removed on completion, neither updates any `$GOPATH/pkg` files or otherwise produces anything.

Answer (score 0):

`go build`

For package main, a binary will be generated by go build. You can dump that in a tmp directory that the OS will clean for you later.

`go build -o /tmp/oswilldeleteme`

Unfortunately, you can not pipe the output of `go build` to the null device. See this issue: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/4851

Comment: "in a tmp directory that the OS will clean for you later"; IMO that should not be assumed. When and *if* `/tmp` is cleaned is an admin decision/configuration, it may be days, at next reboot, or not at all. Also `/tmp` may be limited (e.g. a small partition or a memory filesystem) so it's a bad idea to litter `/tmp` without cleaning up after yourself. (i.e. if you do this a lot perhaps an alias or small script that does something *like* ``DIR=`mktemp -d -t "gobuild"`; go build -o "$DIR/foo"; rm -rf -- "$DIR"``).

Comment: You could run out of disk space before such a time, but I did give it a hardcoded tmp location so every new binary would overwrite the previous one. I think it's hacky to require `make clean` on every build like this even on the very possible chance of having issues with disk space. This is why people complain about Go on the internet https://github.com/flycheck/flycheck/blob/master/flycheck.el#L6084-L6086 It would be awesome if `go build` could be instructed to leave the bin in the tmp workdir it uses.